# How to integrate Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to integrate Google Calendar with DialogFlow, but I've got stuck.

I've added the following code in the Fulfillment section of my project, but I always get Firebase errors:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined
    at createEvent (/user_code/index.js:70:27)
    at authorize (/user_code/index.js:33:5)
    at yourFunctionHandler (/user_code/index.js:122:5)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow- 
    fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:273:44)
```

CODE:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google}= require('googleapis');
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const client_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
  const client_secret = "xxxxxxxxx";
  const redirect_uris = "xxxxxxxxx";

  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  oauth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse('xxxxxxxxx'));
  callback(oauth2Client);
}

function listEvents(auth) {
  google.events.list({
    auth:auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Is there any example that someone could share with me so I can understand what is the process required at least to connect to Google APIs?

thanks

Americo

Comment: have tagged this question properly, because one can recognize zero relation to `dialogflow` or `api.ai` - which might be part of you project, but not part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

with `googleapis` you can simply create the client alike:

```
function listEvents(auth) {

    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});

    calendar.events.list({
...
```

while I cannot see any "firebase errors" nor any "dialog flow"; and I wonder why you've removed the calendar from the [nodejs quick-start](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)? have down-voted the question, because it insults my intellect, to be challenged by such a fabricated question - just compare A to B and you might understand.

Comment: The code you posted above works outside of DialogFlow, and I removed the calendar, because it throws the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined
    at listEvents (/user_code/index.js:70:27)
    at authorize (/user_code/index.js:33:5)
    at yourFunctionHandler (/user_code/index.js:122:5)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:273:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:158:9)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/